# Using VS2017 Publish to Container Registry, how to set tag or image name?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I'm using the VS2017 Publish process to Publish to a Container Registry, but the process always uses a default name for the container and always creates a tag using the date and time.

I would like to specify the tag when running by the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of VS2017 with all updates now allows you to set the publish tag using the Publish to Docker Registry Publish method.